# Formatting date object in an Array with moment is giving an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, momentjs

I am getting the note data from the MongoDB database and Nodejs server base api, and i am trying to format the dates using moment, below is what the notes arrays look like, and also below the note Array is what i have tried in other to achieve this

```
notes = [{
date: "2020-02-27T19:35:52.000Z"
text: "alguma coisa"
_id: "1"

date: "2020-02-27T20:20:27.000Z"
text: "o que"
_id: "2"


date: "2020-02-27T20:21:00.000Z"
text: "o"
_id: "3"
}]


getFunction(){
this.api.get("/notes/", _id).subscribe(
      data => {
        let response = data as any;
        let ret = JSON.parse(response._body);

        this.notesData = ret;
        let retNow = this.notesData.map(o => { 
          Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
            let d = moment(new Date(o[k]))
            if (d.isValid()) o[k] = moment().format("dddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");
          })
        })
        console.log("Note" retNow)
      }, error => {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    );}
```

my HTML

{{note.date}}

The date was formatted right, but the problem is, all the dates are the same, and they are all current date(today's date)
   please what am i doing wrong here,

Comment: i think it should be `d.format()` instead of `moment().format()` because that would just create a new moment object with the current date

Comment: Thank you very much, this ideal work, but with a date is still not correctly formatted, instead of 11, February 2020, it's giving a return of 2, Nov 2020, do you by any chance know a way i can resolve this? thank you

Comment: i can't think of a reason why your date object is parsed differently, from the above example it looks like it is ISO8601 which should not have any problems, maybe you can [explicitly set the date format when parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this

```
moment(YOUR_DATE).format(DATE_FORMAT);
moment('2020-02-27T20:21:00.000Z').format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");
```

Result: 28-Feb-2020 01:51

Comment: awesome, thank you, this solved my problem and also help me manipulate date in the exact way I wanted, looking at your example helped me do this,  if (d.isValid()) o[k] = moment(d).format("dddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");